# CUDA: creating logical picture of grid

Tags: cuda

I've just started learning CUDA and I'm stuck at a fundamental concept: grids. I've read that grid is just a logical collection of blocks (?), but I'm unable to create a picture of the scene in my mind. I have a clear picture of threads and blocks in my mind and know where they relate to in physical GPU. Block go to cores and threads go to stream-processors. But where does grid fit into this picture?

Some analogies would be appreciated and would make understanding easier.

P.s.- I'm learning from udacity.

```
    #include "reference_calc.cpp"
#include "utils.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4* const rgbaImage,
                       unsigned char* const greyImage,
                       int numRows, int numCols)
{
    int x,y,i; // i is index for 1D array greyImage. x and y for rgbaImage
    i = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) + blockIdx.x;
    x= (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    y= (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y;

    if(x < numCols && y < numRows)
    {
        greyImage[i] = (0.299f * rgbaImage[y].x) + (0.587f * rgbaImage[y].y) + (0.114f * rgbaImage[y].z);
    }

}

void your_rgba_to_greyscale(const uchar4 * const h_rgbaImage, uchar4 * const d_rgbaImage,
                            unsigned char* const d_greyImage, size_t numRows, size_t numCols)
{
  //You must fill in the correct sizes for the blockSize and gridSize
  //currently only one block with one thread is being launched
  const dim3 blockSize(10, 10, 1);  //TODO
  size_t gridSizeX, gridSizeY;
  gridSizeX = numCols + (10 - (numCols % 10) );  //adding some number to make it multiple of 10
  gridSizeY = numRows + (10 - (numRows % 10) );  //adding some number to make it multiple of 10

  const dim3 gridSize( gridSizeX, gridSizeY, 1);  //TODO
  rgba_to_greyscale<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_rgbaImage, d_greyImage, numRows, numCols);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize(); checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
}
```

Comment: [This] (http://geco.mines.edu/tesla/cuda_tutorial_mio/) should help u to understand.

Comment: There is a good diagram in the first few pages of the programming guide which ships in every copy of the CUDA toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually threads go to compute cores (at least if we are referring to the marketing term "cuda cores") and thread-blocks are associated with streaming multiprocessors (SMs, or SMX's in Kepler-speak).

The **GRID** is *all threads created by a kernel launch*.  You can call it the collection of blocks if you want to, since a grid is first hierarchically broken down into blocks, (then warps,) then threads.

For a pictorial representation of this hierarchy, refer to slide 9 of this [webinar deck](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_Webinars_CUDA_Memory_Optimization.pdf).

You can disregard the statement on that slide that "only one kernel can be launched at a time".  That was true in 2009 when that deck was created, but is no longer true on newer devices today.

Comment: That was helpful. Now I'm having trouble in unit 1 code in udacity. I dont know if its incorrect grid size calculation or is there a problem in the kernel itself. Only a thin strip from top is being grey scaled. I'm creating more than required threads due to unknown image dimension. The code is in the main post.